# How to combine 2 data arrays in WP_Query? - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to combine 2 arrays from WP_Query.

To call the 1 data, the code is like this:

```php
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'reply') );
 
        foreach ($query->posts as $p){
         
            echo 'ID :'.$p->ID."<br />\r\n";
        }
```

If using variable, just insert it into WP_Query parameters. Like this:

```php
$args1 = array('post_type' => 'reply');
    $query = new WP_Query($args1);
 
        foreach ($query->posts as $p){
         
            echo 'ID :'.$p->ID."<br />\r\n";
        }
```

But my question is, I want to combine it with `'post_type' => 'topic'`

for example the output for args1

```php
'post_type' => 'reply':

ID :519
ID :517
ID :516
ID :515
ID :514
ID :500
ID :499
ID :485
ID :479
ID :478
```

and args2 for:

```php
'post_type' => 'topic':

ID :498
ID :484
ID :483
ID :474
```

I want to combine both of them. I tried to `array_merge()` and `array_combine()` but the output is not what I expected. Any ideas to solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple post_types with an array, like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => array('reply', 'topic')
    ) );

foreach ($query->posts as $p){     
    echo 'ID :'.$p->ID."<br />\r\n";
}
```

To see more details, please check [this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/).

Comment: Dear Mr M J. I found the solution from this link: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55519/can-i-merge-2-new-wp-queryvariable-s

Comment: Thank you for your kindness to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, from this link: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55519/can-i-merge-2-new-wp-queryvariable-s

So, from what I learn. If you want to combine the array, you need to make another new WP_Query(). 1 WP_Query for your data topic, and 1 WP_Query for your data reply. And make another one for the result. The code look like this:

```
    $query1 = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'topic') );
    $query2 = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'reply') );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query->posts = array_merge($query1->posts, $query2->posts);

    foreach ($wp_query->posts as $p){
        echo 'ID :'.$p->ID."<br />\r\n";
    }
```

Thank you for everyone that answer my question.